# Difference between "ziemlich" & "ganz"

Tags: usage

I learned that *ziemlich* means "quite, rather" and *ganz* means "whole, entire." but I just encountered this tweet:

> ganz leichter Schneefall. sehr dekorativ.

My dictionary agrees that *ganz* can also mean "quite." So now I'd like to know what differences, if any, there are in usage between *ziemlich* and *ganz*?

Comment: Eine *ziemlich* / *ganz* gute Frage.

Comment: _Ganz großes Kino_ / _ziemlich großes Kino_ `:-)`

Comment: @HendrikVogt Can you explain the difference? I'm clearly missing out on the joke here. :)

Comment: @Arthaey: Sorry, it was kind of a bad joke. _Ganz großes Kino_ is a figure of speech and expresses that someone put on a great show. It is also used to describe someone who magnificently failed to accomplish some task. _Ziemlich großes Kino_ is just a big cinema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think, there's little difference, when using *ganz* or *ziemlich*. *Ganz* is a little bit stronger than *ziemlich*, but there isn't much space in between meaning. Most time the difference is vague and indecisive. I think most people will use them spontaneously equally without seeing any difference, though they know/feel a difference subconsciously.

In the end, it's like comparing *very* and *quite* in English. *Very* is more intense and similar to *extremely*. *Quite* add strength as well but is less powerful. Compare *very[=extremely] heavy snowfall* vs *quite heavy snowfall*. The tricky thing is that *ganz* can also share the meaning with *pretty*, *fairly* as in *pretty good* or *fairly difficult* [=to some extent but not very].

First things first:

> Mir geht es ganz schlecht.
>   Mir geht es ziemlich schlecht.

This first sentence means, that I am feeling *very* sick. I am not able to do anything and I just want to stay in bed.
In the latter I am also in a weak constitution, i.e. not healthy. I am feeling sick, but I am able to do the most necessary work (I can go to the grocery store, but though I wish someone else would do).

Another example:

> Du bist ein ganz starker Gegner.
>   Du bist ein ziemlich starker Gegner.

Using *ganz* means your opponent is *very* strong and you need much endurance, concentration to beat him. You have to go a high pace, much deceptions, ... Saying *sehr starker Gegner*, however, sounds much better.
Using *ziemlich* still means your opponent is good but you are better. It's not easy to beat him, though. You still have to fight, but you can allow yourself doing mistakes and forgive good chances without risking your win.

Regarding your example (but I will turn to the opposite, as it's less common to talk of *ganz leichter Schneefall*):

> Es ist ganz (schön) starker Schneefall.
>   Es ist ziemlich starker Schneefall.

Aside first: Using also *schön* sounds better to me. I don't know if it just regional, but in this example I would never omit it. In this case it makes the meaning even more powerful, more intense like *very very much*. Again, it sounds slightly better to me using *sehr starker Schneelfall*.

Now what I want to express by saying the first sentence:
Let's imagine the situation that I am driving my car through a heavy snowfall. Then I mean: 'I don't see much'. I have to drive very slowly and carefully. I have to concentrate very much on keeping the lane.
Same situation for the latter one. In that case, I focus on the fact that the snowfall is disturbing, annoying. I still have to drive carefully, but I drive a lot faster because it isn't that dangerous.

Both variation can also stress my astonishment how much snow falls, i.e. that the degree of intensity is more than I expected.

As mentioned above, *ganz* can also mean the pretty same thing as *pretty* does:

> Das Essen war ganz gut.

In this context, *ganz* can be translated to *pretty*, or *fairly*. It wasn't good but not bad either. It was okay.

Comment: I don't quite agree: _Sometimes_ there is very little difference, yes. But take the example "ganz leichter Schneefall". You emphasize that's it's really little snow. (And I can help but have the connotation "very nice".) ["Ziemlich leichter Schneefall"](http://www.google.de/#q="ziemlich+leichter+schneefall") is hardly ever used, and then the context is different: you emphasize that it's not that bad. (See also my comment to the question for another example.)

Comment: @HendrikVogt As you mentioned: *Ziemlich leichter Schneefall* is barely said. I would daresay: Never. If you say *ganz leichter Schneefall* you stress that it is actual not noteworthy. But saying *ziemlich leichter Schneefall* you neutralize *leicht*. And this sounds odd.

Comment: @Em1: of course you can also diminish *leicht* by using *ziemlich* - only it's not used very often used. Example: *"Eine ziemlich leichte Aufgabe"* (of course this is not the same than *"Eine ganz leichte Aufgabe"*).

Comment: @Takkat Good example. *ganz leichte Aufgabe* -> you can solve it *aus dem effeff* - *ziemlich leichte Aufgabe* -> you have to put low effort into it. But note: The meaning of *leicht* is quite different to the snowfall example (*easy* vs *few*)

Comment: Danke für die Situationsbeispiele! Sie machen die Unterschiede klar.

Comment: Imho you tend to over interpretate the words. Maybe you would only say "Mir geht es ziemlich schlecht" while you still can go to the bakery - if John Wayne would say it, he will die in 3 seconds. Or "Es ist ziemlich starker Schneefall" might be disturbing and annoying to you in your example. It can as well be said from a sportsman, hoping for good race conditions.

Comment: @userunknown I think, the actual difference is quite indefinite and maybe affiliated to the speaker's association. You will find much examples to disprove my explanation. In every context you have to reconsider if the connotation changes a bit. Nonetheless I maintain that I cover most situation.

Comment: I accept that fine distinctions of usage like this can't have a simple, definitive answer that's true in all cases. But seeing all these examples can help me build up an idea of what connotations are associated with each and use that as a rule of thumb.

Answer (score 5):

While I do agree with Em1 that *sometimes* the difference between *ziemlich* and *ganz* is vague and indecisive, I'd like to discuss a few cases where there's quite some difference indeed. (Let me point out that we're only talking about the adverbs here, not *ziemlich* and *ganz* as adjectives.)

As you already mention in the question, *ganz* can mean *very* or *entirely* (think of *ganz und gar*), but it can also mean *quite* or *rather*. In your example sentence

> ganz leichter Schneefall. sehr dekorativ.

*ganz* means *very*. You can't replace *ganz* with *ziemlich* here (see also my comment to Em1's answer). Other examples where *ziemlich* won't work at all:

> Bleib' mal ganz locker.  —  Stay cool.
>   Komm' bitte ganz schnell.  —  Come quickly, please.

(I'm not sure if the *ganz* should be translated at all in these sentences; its meaning again is *very*.)

#### Examples where both *ganz* and *ziemlich* are possible

If you say that a dish tastes *ziemlich lecker*, then usually it tastes better than a dish tasting *ganz lecker*. The reason is that here the *ziemlich* reinforces *lecker*, while *ganz* weakens it. (I'm not sure if there's an analogous difference between *rather tasty* and *quite tasty*.) Other examples where usually *ziemlich* is used to reinforce and *ganz* is used to weaken (and where I would translate *ganz* as *quite*):

> ziemlich gut / ganz gut,
>   ziemlich nett / ganz nett,
>   ziemlich interessant / ganz interessant.

But be careful, this depends a lot on the intonation - *ziemlich* can also be used to weaken an adjective. And I think Em1 is right that some people won't see the difference in these examples.

Comment: Agree. I think it is really hard to get the nuance of *ganz*. It's a bit indefinite. Your answer is a good complement.

Comment: Eine Reihenfolge zwischen "ziemlich lecker" und "ganz lecker" kann man nicht ausmachen. Es kann so sein, es kann aber auch anders sein, wie Du selbst sagst. Beides hängt von der Betonung ab.

Answer (score 1):

*Ganz* means "whole," or "complete." As such, it is sometimes stronger and sometimes weaker than *ziemlich*.

*Ich bin ganz krank.*: I am "entirely" sick. (Can't do anything.) Versus *Ich bin ziemlich krank.* (I'm rather sick, but can do some things for myself). Here, *ganz* is stronger than *ziemlich*.

*Es ist ganz gut*. It's "good" (all around, but nothing great). Versus *Es ist ziemlich gut.* (It is rather good, borders on great.) Here *ganz* is weaker than *ziemlich*.

Comment: In general I agree. But I don't think that natives would say *Ich bin ganz krank.* They would rather say *Ich bin total/sehr/ziemlich krank.*

Comment: Diese Kommentare machen mich immer ganz krank.

Comment: @Em1: Actually, the original example (from above) was "Mir geht es ziemlich schlecht." I just did a "take-off" on it.

Answer (score -6):

The difference is that "ganz" is always 100% where "ziemlich" is something like 90%.

So the snow is 100% or completely "leicht"

Comment: Sicher? *Wie war deine Klausur?* - *Joa, ganz gut.*